# Access excel sheet data into our app

Tags: cordova, filesystems, filereader, android-sdcard, import-from-excel

We have placed excel in my android mobile `SdCard` in some location.We need excel data access into My app.
We flowed this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader
so We tried like this but this not work form me

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

we tried like this:--

```
function init(){
alert("selectItems");
  //document.addEventListener("deviceready", getDeviceLocation , false); 
 getDeviceLocation();
}
function getDeviceLocation() {
    alert("Ready");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }
function gotFS(fileSystem) {

    alert("fileSystem");

    fileSystem.root.getFile("test_excel.xlsx", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
alert("FileEntry");
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
alert("gotFile");
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {

 alert("file");

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
     alert("ineral");
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
 alert("ineral1");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
     alert("ineral2");
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("error");
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

but `gotFS` method not called.Please guide me this way right or not.if any other way to do this Please help me